# Add touch listener to button in AndEngine for Android

Tags: android, button, andengine

I am new to AndEngine and I added a button in game scene. Now I want to add a listener to it.

```
button = new ButtonSprite(25, 310, activity.exitButtonRegion, BaseActivity.getSharedInstance().getVertexBufferObjectManager());
button.setPosition(activity.mCamera.getWidth() / 2 + activity.mCamera.getWidth() / 3, 0);          

attachChild(button);
```

How can I add a touch listener?

Answer (score 1):

Just use this structure and don't forget to use registerTouchArea method

```
mButton = new ButtonSprite(400  , 400, myTiledTextureRegion.getTextureRegion(0), myTiledTextureRegion.getTextureRegion(1), 
            activity.getVertexBufferObjectManager(), new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(ButtonSprite pButtonSprite, float pTouchAreaLocalX,
                        float pTouchAreaLocalY) {

                                 Toast.makeText(MenuScene.this.activity, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }
            });

    this.registerTouchArea(mButton); 
    this.attachChild(mButton);
```